# Flex - deleting a string in text input leaves a square symbol

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

When I type something in a  and the delete it with Ctrl + Backspace the word gets deleted but then a strange square symbol appears.

The browser I am using is Chrome.

Also I tried to ignore some keyboard keys to see if this will workaround the problem but with no success:

```
   function onKeyDownPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
      if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.CONTROL){
         //Keyboard event ignored
         return;
      }
   }
```

Any ideas why do I get this square symbol and how to ignore it?

Comment: Have you tried using IE?

Comment: Yes and the problem probably is somehow related to the browser, because I cannot reproduce the same effect on IE.

Comment: Ok, I overrided the expected behavior for Control+Backspace and now it seems to work. Obviously not all browsers support the Ctrl+Backspace combination.

Comment: Post your own answer and mark as solved to help people with the same problem in the future!

Comment: I think I don't have the required reputation so that's why I commented here. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ummm.. i dont think you need a required reputation ammount to answer you own questions. Let me check

Comment: I just checked in one of my unaswered questions and i can answer my own questions, right at the bottom there is a big button that says "Answer my own question" Does that not appear?

Comment: Ah, I missed that - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overrided the expected behavior for Control+Backspace and now it seems to work. Obviously not all browsers support the Ctrl+Backspace combination.

```
function onKeyDownPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
   if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACKSPACE){
        var deltedString:String = 
            inputTxt.text.substring(0, inputTxt.text.lastIndexOf(" "));
            inputTxt.text = deletedString;
   }
}
```